# How to display Date?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, database, vb.net

I want to display date from table in like this:

```
Feb 2017 -24, 25

Feb 2018 -26
```

I have values in table:

```
02/24/2017

02/05/2017

03/31/2017

04/15/2017

02/11/2017

02/25/2017

04/29/2017
```

i want out put:

```
Feb-2017 : 04,05,24,25

March-2017 : 31

Aprial-2017: 15,29
```

Comment: Which language you want to display date in SQL-Server or C# or VB?

Comment: I want to use in VB

Comment: if he inputs are of type `DateTime` then use `.ToString("format here")` with specific format to get what you need

Comment: but i don't know how to get.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
select datename(month, PackageDate) + ' ' + convert(varchar, year(PackageDate)),
    stuff((
            select ',' + convert(varchar, day(PackageDate))
            from tbl_PackageDate
            where datename(month, t2.PackageDate) = datename(month, PackageDate)
                and year(PackageDate) = year(t2.PackageDate)
                and Packageid = 86
            order by PackageDate
            for xml path('')
            ), 1, 1, '')
from tbl_PackageDate t2
where Packageid = 86
group by datename(month, PackageDate),
    year(PackageDate);
```

#### [Demo](http://rextester.com/NLTD65160)

Comment: When i use parameter  for particular package then its display data from whole table

Comment: select datename(month, PackageDate) + ' ' + convert(varchar, year(PackageDate)),
    stuff((
            select ',' + convert(varchar, day(PackageDate))
            from tbl_PackageDate
            where datename(month, t2.PackageDate) = datename(month, PackageDate)
                and year(PackageDate) = year(t2.PackageDate)
            order by PackageDate
            for xml path('')
            ), 1, 1, '')
from tbl_PackageDate t2 where Packageid=86  
group by datename(month, PackageDate),
    year(PackageDate) ;

Comment: You need to add the field in the subquery where clause. Updated the answer. try now

Comment: can Guide me how use it in subquery

Comment: it show the error:  line 7
Column 'tbl_PackageDate.Packageid' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @Dhaval - Missed that bit, sorry. You can put the value directly. Updated the answer. Please try now.